# How to monitor AWS Fsx ONTAP Filesystem Usage using lambda function and cloudwatch metrics

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am first time trying to work on the `aws lambda` function to get the monitoring for `FSxN` IE `FSx` for ONTAP Storage in AWS.

Here I want to get the `StorageCapacity` and `StorageTier` in order to achieve total `filesystemUsed` percentage for monitoring.

I have tried the code below after a lot of search and trial but got an error.

## Code tried:

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    fsx = boto3.client('fsx')
    filesystems = fsx.describe_file_systems()
    table = []
    for filesystem in filesystems.get('FileSystems'):
        status = filesystem.get('Lifecycle')
        filesystem_id = filesystem.get('FileSystemId')
        table.append(filesystem_id)
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    result = []
    for filesystem_id in table:
        current_time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
        response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
            MetricDataQueries=[
                {
                    'Id': 'm1',
                    'MetricStat': {
                        'Metric': {
                            'Namespace': 'AWS/FSx',
                            'MetricName': 'StorageCapacity',
                            'Dimensions': [
                                {
                                    'Name': 'FileSystemId',
                                    'Value': filesystem_id
                                },
                                {
                                    'Name': 'StorageTier',
                                    'Value': 'SSD'
                                },
                                {
                                    'Name': 'DataType',
                                    'Value': 'All'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'Period': 60,
                        'Stat': 'Sum'
                    },
                    'ReturnData': True
                },
                {
                    'Id': 'm2',
                    'MetricStat': {
                        'Metric': {
                            'Namespace': 'AWS/FSx',
                            'MetricName': 'StorageUsed',
                            'Dimensions': [
                                {
                                    'Name': 'FileSystemId',
                                    'Value': filesystem_id
                                },
                                {
                                    'Name': 'StorageTier',
                                    'Value': 'SSD'
                                },
                                {
                                    'Name': 'DataType',
                                    'Value': 'All'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'Period': 60,
                        'Stat': 'Sum'
                    },
                    'ReturnData': True
                }
            ],
            StartTime='2023-01-20T00:01:00Z',
            EndTime='2023-01-20T00:02:00Z'
        )
        storage_capacity = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Values'][0]
        storage_used = response['MetricDataResults'][1]['Values'][0]
        result.append({'filesystem_id': filesystem_id,'storage_capacity': storage_capacity, 'storage_used': storage_used})
    return result
```

## Error after execution

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "list index out of range",
  "errorType": "IndexError",
  "requestId": "a09573f2-87ea-4464-afc0-8b196f669415",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 75, in lambda_handler\n    storage_capacity = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Values'][0]\n"
  ]
}
```

## MetricDataResults for metric(`m1`) and metric(`m2`)

```
{'MetricDataResults': [
                        {'Id': 'm1', 'Label': 'StorageCapacity', 'Timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 1, tzinfo=tzlocal())], 'Values': [925308932096.0], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}, 
                        {'Id': 'm2', 'Label': 'StorageUsed', 'Timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 1, tzinfo=tzlocal())], 'Values': [2439143424.0], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}], 'Messages': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '479a53b2-b5f5-46c0-b79d-278d803df94b', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '479a53b2-b5f5-46c0-b79d-278d803df94b', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '923', 'date': 'Sat, 21 Jan 2023 18:06:35 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
{'MetricDataResults': [
                        {'Id': 'm1', 'Label': 'StorageCapacity', 'Timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 1, tzinfo=tzlocal())], 'Values': [925308932096.0], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}, 
                        {'Id': 'm2', 'Label': 'StorageUsed', 'Timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 1, tzinfo=tzlocal())], 'Values': [2593112064.0], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}], 'Messages': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'db9ad0a4-0a24-4f1d-be60-55bde63fd49b', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'db9ad0a4-0a24-4f1d-be60-55bde63fd49b', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '923', 'date': 'Sat, 21 Jan 2023 18:06:35 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Please help/hint something to get into the solution.

Comment: For starters, you can `print(response)` and check the logs to see what kind of data you're actually getting back.  I would guess `MetricDataQueries` is subtly wrong - it can be difficult to build correct input to `GetMetricData` api call.  I recommend you debug this code locally until you're happy with the behavior, before proceeding to upload to lambda.

Comment: @erik258  thanks , It i added the print statement to debug it more,  I see the `filesystem_id` is not also getting looped over.